# Spring MVC: No handler found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'Resource_PHASE'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jboss, spring-portlet-mvc

As usual it seems I have done everything right but for the ghost my ajax call fails with the error "No handler found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'Resource_PHASE'".

The handler url here is "getAllFruit" which i pick up from the js ajax call and map it against the actual url "getAllFruitURL" in the controller through the mapper file in fruits-resource-url.js.

There are other similar ajax methods too which are written here and all are working fine except this new one. I guess I am missing something there. Please any advise. The spellings are correct for the handler.

Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class FruitCtrl 
{    
    @Autowired
    private FruitAdapter fruitAdapter;

    @ResourceMapping("getAllFruitURL")
    public void getAllFruits(ResourceResponse response) throws IOException 
    {       
        // code for call to service     
    }
}
```

Javascript class from where ajax call is made
fruit.js

```
$function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:getAllFruit,
        success:function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

Resource File from where the resource is read

fruits-resource-url.js

```
var getAllFruit = replaceResourceID("getAllFruitURL");
//<portlet-resourceURL id="RESOURCE_ID_PLACEHOLDER"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had found the ghost!

I have been running my application in debug mode. As such to avoid an automatic rebuild of the app in the server I deselected "Build Automatically" option which did not allow the .class file to get updated in the .war file despite a republish on the server.

Lesson learnt: The server doesn't give a damn whether the app is built or not. It would stick to its job and start publishing the app on the server.

So, there are only two basic steps that need to be taken care of while working with resource rendering:

1. The handler url name mentioned in the ajax call url attribute is an exact match against the actual url "getAllFruitURL" in the controller (if we are using a resource mapper js file as in my case, then against the mapper file in fruits-resource-url.js)
   And this was taken care already!
   P.S. Common sense though common can be volatile at times for varying reasons!:)